# On-premises TFS. Change Git Location/ Use External

Tags: git, tfs

I am not able to answer myself the following questions concerning git handling by an on-premises TFS:

- Where does TFS store git repositories?
- How can I change that location?
- Or is every git repository restricted to reside on the TFS?
- **Is it possible to use a different git repository hosted on-premises on a different server and give the on-premises TFS full access to this so that everything is working just like it is a "normal" TFS git?** (I know that I can add an external git repository to the build process but what I want is a "real" integration - thus the code explorer should be able to browse that repository)
- And is there some kind of resource explaining the internal handling of git by the TFS? I would love to dive deeper and know what TFS does in the background. Or in different words: What is Microsofts excuse for blocking 'external' git repositories? As I fear the above scenario is just not possible to realize...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: TFS stores Git *data* in the Collection database. This choice is congruent with the initial design of transactional coherence and simplified backup strategy (no data dispersed in multiple files/filesystems).
**All** TFS data is in a SQL Server database: filesystem is used only as a cache to avoid expensive operations.
As a consequence you cannot manage "external" repositories.

If you really want to drill down on how this is accomplished, read [Richard Banks' post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html).